# Integral constraint vs derivative constraint in calculus of variations problem

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

My lecture notes compare two problems, and state that they are equal:

> $$\text {maximize } U(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho t}u(x(t))dt, \text { s.t. } \int_0^\infty x(t)dt\leq s\in \mathbb R$$

The notes state that this can be reformulated as:

> $$\text {maximize } U(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho t}u(x(t))dt, \text { s.t. }$$ $$ \dot u(t)=-x(t),$$ $$u(0)=s,$$ $$u(t)\geq 0 \text { for }t\geq 0$$

I sort of understand why this would capture the same thing, but I don't understand how this conclusion is drawn.

**How do we formally derive the second problem from the first one, and vice versa?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t} = -x(t) 
$$

can be written as

$$
u(t) - u(0) = -\int_0^t{\rm d}t'~x(t') ~~~~\Rightarrow~~~~ u(t) = u(0) -
 \int_0^t{\rm d}t'~x(t') 
$$

If you take $u(0) = s$, then this is equivalent to

$$
u(t) = s - \int_0^t{\rm d}t'~x(t') \ge 0
$$

This last inequality comes from the constraint in the original problem. It is important to see that this constraint should only be valid for $t\to\infty$, but if you ensure that $u(t)\ge 0, ~\forall t$ then the constraint is automatically satisfied in the limit.

Comment: So we arbitrarily set $u(0)=s$, and then impose the constraint $u(t)\leq 0$ which is **stronger** than the original constraint, but includes it?

Comment: @Programmer2134 Right